# Is there a std::function type or similar for lambda with auto parameter?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14, auto, generic-lambda

When I assign a lambda to an explicitly typed variable (for example when it is recursive, to capture the function in itself), I use `std::function`.

Consider this silly "bit counting" function as an example:

```
std::function<int(int)> f;
f = [&f](int x){ return x ? f(x/2)+1 : 0; };
```

What about the case when we use an auto parameter to generalize `x`, as introduced in C++14 generic lambda?

```
std::function<int(???)> f;
f = [&f](auto x){ return x ? f(x/2)+1 : 0; };
```

Obviously, I can't place `auto` in the `function` type parameters.

Is there a possibility to define a functor class generically enough to cover the exact case above, but still using lambda for the function definition?

(Don't over-generalize this, only accept a single auto parameter and hard-code the return value.) The use case would be for the scenario like above: capturing the function in itself by reference for recursive calls.

Comment: The problem here, I think, is that a lamba function needs a definitive type - `auto` just lets the compile figure out by itself. It doesn't mean that you can pass the lambda function to any code that has any type in it - the type needs to be known at the compile-time of the lambda function.

Comment: What about `auto& f = [&f](auto x){return x ? f(x/2)+1 : 0;};`? Does that work? (Possibly just `auto` instead of `auto&`.) I don't have a C++14-capable compiler handy, so I can't readily test it.

Comment: `std::function` uses type erasure. I'm fairly certain it is *fundamentally impossible* to write a type-erased function object wrapper that accepts arbitrary types, since every set of argument types needs to *create* a new function, which can only be done if the compiler can see the wrapped *function template*. Workarounds include using a fixed set of sets of parameter types (use an existing sets of overloads / precompute all overloads before the type erasure), or type-erasing the arguments.

Comment: @dyp you can create a type erasure on argument types, or on the function, but doing it on both is intractable *without* reflecting your function (like boost phoenix) into data (basically, recompiling your function on the argument types).  For a concrete example, imagine shipping gcc with your binary, storing the function as a string.  When passed arguments, you determine their type, print out the function for that type, compile a dynamic library, load it, and run the function.  Not quite impossible.  And requires the function be defined as something other than simple C++ code.

Comment: @Yakk Interesting. So this issue is not *type erasure* directly, but the compiler's inability to generate code for the combination of the function and the set of arguments. Erasing the type of a function template by storing it as a string might as well be called type-erasure.

Comment: @dyp yep.  If you work with stuff like OpenCL, your kernels are strings which you compile at run-time.  You can manipulate said kernels using "type information" input at run-time, generating one of an infinite set of possible kernel implementations, compile it, then invoke it.  Of course, doing this *safely* is ridiculously hard other than really simple cases, which is one of the advantage of C++ style template metaprogramming over string-based metaprogramming.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a lambda that calls itself by passing it to itself as a parameter:

```
auto f = [](auto self, auto x) -> int {
    return x ? self(self, x / 2) + 1 : 0;
};

std::cout << f(f, 10);
```

You can then capture that lambda in another lambda, so you don't have to worry about passing it to itself:

```
auto f2 = [&f](auto x) {
    return f(f, x);
};

std::cout << f2(10);
```

Comment: Although you don't answer the actual question (I wanted to type a type name for the functor), I guess I can use it to solve my actual problem (which is too long to explain - I thought I need to explicitly give the functor a type, but I guess I can work around that with your solution in my concrete scenario).

Answer (score 3):

Here is a quick y-combinator based recursive engine:

```
template<class F>
struct recursive_t {
  F f;

  // note Self must be an lvalue reference.  Things get
  // strange if it is an rvalue:
  // invoke makes recursive ADL work a touch better.
  template<class Self, class...Args>
  friend auto invoke( Self& self, Args&&...args )
  -> decltype( self.f( self, std::declval<Args>()... ) )
  {
    return self.f( self, std::forward<Args>(args)... );
  }
  // calculate return type using `invoke` above:
  template<class Self, class...Args>
  using R = decltype( invoke( std::declval<Self>(), std::declval<Args>()... ) );

  template<class...Args>
  R<recursive_t&, Args...> operator()(Args&&...args)
  {
    return invoke( *this, std::forward<Args>(args)... );
  }
  template<class...Args>
  R<recursive_t const&, Args...> operator()(Args&&...args)const
  {
    return invoke( *this, std::forward<Args>(args)... );
  }
};

template<class F>
recursive_t< std::decay_t<F> > recurse( F&& f )
{
  return {std::forward<F>(f)};
}
```

now you can do:

```
auto f = recurse( [](auto&& f, auto x){ return x ? f(x/2)+1 : 0; } );
```

and you get a recursive lambda that doesn't have a `&` capture (which limits its use to the current scope).

Capturing a `std::function` by reference means your lambda's lifetime is the current scope, and every recursive call requires going over type erasure (blocking any possible optimization, like tail-recursion, over the recursive call).  The same holds true of other similar solutions.

The use of `recursive_t` is required rather than using a lambda, because a lambda cannot name itself within itself.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c01b01ca359940a7).

A lambda based version is somewhat simpler in implementation.  Note that you'd need a different type function for mutable and immutable lambdas:

```
template<class F>
auto recurse( F&& f ) {
  return [f=std::forward<F>(f)](auto&&...args){
    return f(f, decltype(args)(args)...);
  };
};
```

The `recursive_t` works like:

```
auto fib = recurse( [](auto&& fib, int x){ if (x<2) return 1; return fib(x-1)+fib(x-2); } );
```

the lambda version works like:

```
auto fib = recurse( [](auto&& self, int x){ if (x<2) return 1; return self(self, x-1)+self(self,x-2); } );
```

which I, personally, find more awkward.

It is also harder to describe the type of `recurse`.  For the `recursive_t` version, `recurse` is of type:

```
((A->B)->A->B)->(A->B)
```

which is awkward, but a finite type.

The lambda version is trickier.  The type of the function argument to `recursive` is of type:

```
F:= F->A->B
```

which is annoyingly infinite, and then `recurse` is of type

```
F->A->(A->B)
```

which inherits the infinity.

Anyhow, the `recurse` return value can then be stored in a mundane `std::function`, or not stored in any type-erased container.